# How to use "autoMirrored" attribute directly on images in RTL layout

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

With "autoMirrored" flag in xml it is now easy to do mirroring of drawable in android 4.4 Kitkat. But is there any way to do this directly with various image resources used in application without using xml ?

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically you can use [**`setAutoMirrored`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setAutoMirrored(boolean)) on Drawable like:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

Drawable arrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_right_arrow);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (arrow != null) {
           arrow.setAutoMirrored(true);
    }
}

image.setImageDrawable(arrow);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by `Drawable.setAutoMirrored (boolean mirrored)` call. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setAutoMirrored(boolean)